# Unable to use mv with wildcards in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, wildcards, mv

I am trying to use the command

```
mv ./?*20?* new_directory
```

running `ls ./?*20?*` gives multiple matches, but the above command gives me

```
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

I tried `mv './?*20?*' new_directory` but quotes don't support wildcards. Manually moving a file with its name works, I have already created `new_directory`

I tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/173287/cp-command-not-working-with-wildcards-on-mac-os-x), which again results in an error.

Some of the files I am trying to move are,

```
./031120.py             ./121120.txt            ./160920.py             ./171120.txt            ./191120class.txt       ./250820.py
./110820.py             ./131020.py             ./170920.py             ./191120.txt            ./201020.py             ./260820.py
```

EDIT:
I tried `mv ./?*20?* 'new_directory/.'` and `mv ./?*20?* new_directory/.` and am getting the same,
`usage: ...` as mentioned above.

using `set -x` and executing `mv ./?*20?* new_directory` I get

```
+ mv 031120.py 110820.py 121120.txt 131020.py 160920.py 170920.py 171120.txt 191120.txt 201020.py 250820.py 260820.py new_directory
```

Comment: What happens when you use `mv ./?*20?* new_directory/.`? Please [edit] your question and add this information, don't use comments to answer.

Comment: Try running `set -x` first so you can see what your `mv` statement looks like after the shell has done the glob expansion. Maybe you have so many matches that it exceeds the maximum command length and gets truncated or something. If that's the case, you may have to use `xargs(1)` so you can control how many filenames get passed to each invocation of `mv`.

Comment: @Spiff yeah that works, do you want to answer the question or should I?

Comment: @Ceres I'm not quite sure what you're saying fixed it exactly ("set -x" by itself shouldn't have fixed it as far as I know), so I guess I'd better let you write the Answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mv ./?*20?* new_directory` runs `mv 031120.py 110820.py 121120.txt 131020.py 160920.py 170920.py 171120.txt 191120.txt 201020.py 250820.py 260820.py new_directory` as pointed out by @Spiff.
We can use the find and exec argument to move the files one by one.

```
find . -name '?*20.?*' -maxdepth 1 -exec mv '{}' ./new_directory \;
```

find gets each files and runs the exec with the filename parameter.